# How to make steps optional in multistep form

Tags: forms

I want to skip some steps in multistep page break forms.

Let's say a user filled the first step then at the end there will be message.

Do you like to go to part 2 of the form or submit the form now?

Yes / No

If they choose Yes it should submit the form without going to next page break. If they select No then it will submit the form without next step and shows thank you message.

Comment: which module are you used?

Comment: Just webform module. There is a field called "Page break" and gives you multiple steps. I want user to skip some steps if he don't want and submit the form without going to other steps.

Comment: did you tried mulitstep registration form

Comment: Multistep is used for only registration form. I want it applied in any webform I would like to.